# Associativity of symmetric set difference

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, associativity

The symmetric difference $A$ $\Delta$ $B$ of $A$ and $B$ is defined as $(A - B) \cup (B - A)$. (The set of elements that belong to $A$ or $B$ but not both.)

(a) Construct a truth table to show that $\Delta$ is associative.

(b) Show that $x$ belongs to $A$ $\Delta$ $(B$ $\Delta$ $C)$ if and only if $x$ belongs to an odd number of the sets $A$, $B$ and $C$ and use this observation to give a second proof that $\Delta$ is associative.

For part (a), I'd be grateful is someone could post the full truth table, as I'm not entirely sure what column headings they are looking for.

For part (b), this is what I did:

(For the left to right implication) Let $x \in $ $A$ $\Delta$ $(B$ $\Delta$ $C)$. Then, by the definition of $\Delta$, we have either $x \in $ $A$ or $x \in $ $(B$ $\Delta$ $C)$ but not both. So if $x \in A$ then either it is not in $B$ nor $C$ or it is in both $B$ and $C$. So here $x$ can be in just $A$, or in $A, B$ and $C$. If $x \in (B$ $\Delta$ $C)$, then $x \notin A$. So by a similar logic $x$ can be in $B$ or $C$, but not both. The implication works both ways, hence the 'iff'.

However, I'm not sure how this proves associativity. I tried to write it as

$A$ $\Delta$ $(B$ $\Delta$ $C)$  = ($A$ $\Delta$ $B$)  $\cap$  ($A$ $\Delta$ $C$) $\cap$ ($B$ $\Delta$ $C$)  $ \cup$ $ (A\cap B\cap C)$
And then associativity would follow by swapping $A$ and $C$ but I'm not sure if this is the right way of doing it.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a proof:

$$
\begin{align}
\left(A \triangle B \right) \triangle C &= \left (A \cup B \cup C \right) \cap \left (A \cup B^{c} \cup C^{c} \right) \cap (A^{c} \cup B \cup C^{c}) \cap (A^{c} \cup B^{c} \cup C) \\
&= (B \cup C \cup A) \cap (B \cup C^{c} \cup A^{c}) \cap (B^{c} \cup C \cup A^{c}) \cap (B^{c} \cup C^{c} \cup A) \\
&= (B \bigtriangleup C) \bigtriangleup A \\
&= A \bigtriangleup (B \bigtriangleup C)
\end{align}
$$

The proof of symmetric difference operator associativity comes from late professor David Meredith home page: http://online.sfsu.edu/meredith/Exploration_and_Proof/divided_difference.pdf

available at 2024.04.01 at https://web.archive.org/web/20210410235520/http://online.sfsu.edu/meredith/Exploration_and_Proof/divided_difference.pdf

practically one page paper contains propositions and eventually proof of associativity.
Proof assume that operator $\triangle$ is commutative as proven below from proposition 7:

$$A\triangle B=(A\cup B)\cap(A^{c}\cup B^{c})=(B\cup A)\cap(B^{c}\cup A^{c})=B\triangle A$$

Hope it helps.

Comment: Your PDF link returns a 404.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a truth table with an intermediate column;

$$\ \begin{array}{|ccc|c|c|}
\hline
A&B&C&A\Delta B&(A\Delta B)\Delta C\\
\hline
0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&1&0&1\\
0&1&0&1&1\\
0&1&1&1&0\\
1&0&0&1&1\\
1&0&1&1&0\\
1&1&0&0&0\\
1&1&1&0&1\\
\hline
\end{array}$$

It remains to do a similar array with $A \Delta (B\Delta C)$ and see they have similar last columns.

---

A completely different method (afterthought... 6 years later):

In fact, if one uses the equivalent boolean formulation with XOR (eXclusive OR) operator, one can easily check that the following function:

$$XOR(x,y)=x(1-y)+y(1-x)=x+y-2xy$$

is such that

$$XOR(0,0)=0, \ \ XOR(0,1)=1, \ \ XOR(1,0)=1, \ \ XOR(1,1)=0$$

i.e., "works" like the $\Delta$ operator.

It is now routine calculation to show thay

$$XOR(XOR(a,b),c)=XOR(a+b-2ab,c)=(a+b-2ab)+c-2(a+b-2ab)c$$

Finally:

$$XOR(XOR(a,b),c)=a+b+c-2(ab+bc+ca)+4abc\tag{1}$$

which is a symmetrical expression in variables $a,b,c$.

It is routine verification that $XOR(a,XOR(b,c))$ gives the same result as (1).

Comment: Thank you. That's much clearer. What are your thoughts on the proof of associativity in part (b)?

Comment: 1) Of course, I didn't do the truth table for $A\Delta(B \Delta C)$ with intermediate column $B \Delta C$ because it is your part of the task...2) For your proof by taking an element, it looks rather convenient.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the representation, $(a,b)\in \mathbb F_2\times \mathbb F_2$
if $x\in A$, then $a=1$ otherwise $a=0$

for example,if $x\in A$ but $x\notin B$

then $x\mapsto(1,0)$, define exist function: $[ a,b]=a+b$

and $x\in A\Delta B\Leftrightarrow [a,b]=1$

and you can view $(A\Delta B)\Delta C $ as$[[a,b],c]=(a+b)+c=a+(b+c)=[a,[b,c]]$

So, $x\in (A\Delta B)\Delta C\Leftrightarrow x\in A\Delta(B\Delta C)$

Actually, $(P(S),\Delta,\cap)$ is a Ring, and you can prove the distribution law as follow.

Consider the exist fuction like $x\in (A\Delta B)\cap C\Leftrightarrow (a+b)\times c=0\Leftrightarrow ac+bc=0\Leftrightarrow x\in (A\cap C)\Delta (B\cap C)$

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. That said, please don't answer old questions that already have good answers. When you do, you put them on the active question queue, so waste the time of folks like me who watch that queue. If you want to help, look for new questions that don't yet have answers. Only answer those where the OP has done some work.